# Is it possible to change color of different hyperlinks in same body tag in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink

As the title says, I want to create say 4 different hyperlinks inside one body tag whilst the color values for LINK, ALINK and VLINK of all 4 hyperlinks should be different.

From my current knowledge in HTML, since the values of the three properties are set inside the body tag

```html
<body link="pink" alink="blue" vlink="yellow">
.....
</body>
```

I don't know if such a method exists.

There obviously doesn't seem to be much use of it but I am just curious.

Comment: share your code for better understanding what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML itself? No.

CSS was introduced two decades ago as a means to describe the appearance of HTML and other markup documents. Its selector syntax allows you to distinguish between links by various means.

e.g.

Link inside the footer:

```
footer a:link { 
    color: blue;
}
```

For more information see:

- [MDN CSS tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS)
- [The selectors specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: `In HTML itself? No.` I love straight forward answers, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<body>
 <a class="link" style="color:pink;">link</a>
 <a class="alink" style="color:blue;">alink </a>
 <a class="vlink" style="color:yellow;"> vlink</a>
</body>
```

Are you asking something like this?

Comment: hmm i don't think this is it, i don't know if you understood what i meant by alink,vlink and link but what i want is that the link colours should change, after i've clicked on the link once it by default becomes purple, i want to change that colour for different links in ONE html doc

Comment: a:link {
    color: pink;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: yellow;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: blue;
} you can try this.

Answer (score -1):

I could be off, but I feel like this would make a little more sense then doing it all in html.

**html**

```
<body>
  <a class=link href="#"></a>
  <a class=alink href="#"></a>
  <a class=vlink href="#"></a>
</body>
```

**css**

```
.link {
  color: pink;
}
.alink {
  color: blue;
}
.vlink {
  color: yellow;
}
```

That being said, you'd probably want to rename those classes to increase readability

Comment: Please change <\body> to </body> :)

Comment: Whoops! Thanks! Writing code on a cell phone = no fun

Comment: Haha.Welcome.That's great :)